# Why does the code that I put within a region show as commented out

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm developing an multi-platform app for iOS and Android in Xamarin Studio. I'm using Xamarin 5.8 on Mac OS X 10.10.2.
So I got certain pieces of code that I only want to run for iOS or Android.

But when I add a region, my code between the region show's up like this:
[image: region]

I've tried restarting Xamarin and cleaning my project but it doesn't work.
So my question is how can I resolve this? so my code doesn't appear like it's commented out.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually not a region, it's a conditional compilation symbol. It means that this code will only build if you are targeting an iOS device otherwise it won't be included in your actual code. I guess you have selected to build it for an Android device that's why you see this code in gray.

Btw did you checked if **IOS** is added to your Conditional compilation symbols in project properties under Build tab?

Comment: I selected to run it on an iPhone actually. And I can't find the Conditional compilation symbols in my project properties.

Comment: @Bas I made a screenshot about it and highlighted that part with red. I hope this will help: http://imgur.com/mdl7tDH

Comment: Xamarin should be adding the [`__IOS__` symbol (and various others)](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_4_-_platform_divergence_abstraction_divergent_implementation/#Conditional_Compilation) for you automatically.

Comment: @patridge Exactly I also thought that. I still didn't figure it out how I can resolve my problem.